# Undefined variable:user laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I keep on getting this error whenever I try to enter the upload page.

Can anybody help?

I have already done the compact part to make sure that the variable is being passed to the view and also my route should be ok I think.

I tried using dd but all it does is keep on showing me the error

Error: Undefined variable: user (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Evaluation\resources\views\upload.blade.php)

Here are my codes:

upload.blade.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/userUpload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {{  csrf_field()  }}

    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$user->id}}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imageInput" class="control-label col-sm-3">Upload Image</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="file" name="file">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

UploadController:

```
public function upload(){

    return view(‘upload’);
}

public function store(Request $request,$id){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

   var_dump('has file '.$request->hasFile('file'));
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $size = $image->getClientSize();
        $id = $request->user_id;
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);

        $Image = new Image;
        $Image->name = $name;
        $Image->size = $size;
       //  $Image->user_id = $id;         
        //$Image->save();
             $user->find($id);
               dd($user);
       $user->Images()->save($Image);
    }
    return redirect('/home');
}

public function test(){
    $user = user_information::where('id')->get();
    return view('upload', compact('user'));
}
```

Route: (this are my route)

```
Route::get('/UploadUser/upload','UploadController@upload’);
Route::post('/UploadUser','UploadController@store');
Route::post('/UploadUser/upload', 'UploadController@test');
```

Another question: I keep on getting this error when i try to upload a file, so what should I do?

Here is the error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`form`.`images`,
>   CONSTRAINT `images_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES
>   `usere_information` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `images` (`name`,
>   `size`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (download.png,
>   4247, 1, 2017-10-25 08:54:57, 2017-10-25 08:54:57))

Image model:

```
class Image extends Model
{

   protected $fillable = array('name','size','user_id');

    public function user_informations() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\user_information', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Images table:

```
   Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('size');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); 
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user_informations'); 
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

User_information table:

```
 Schema::create('user_informations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
             $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->binary('signature');  
            $table->String('Name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

User_information model:

```
class user_information extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = array('signature', 'Name');
    protected $table = 'user_informations';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
        public function Images() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Image','user_id');
    }
}
```

[image]

How to get the image?
Here is the view folder:

```
@foreach ($data as $object)
    <b>Name: </b>{{ $object->Name }}<br><br>
 <a href="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object->id.'/edit') }}">Edit</a><br>
    @foreach ($data3 as $currentUser)
    <img src="{{ asset('public/images/' . $currentUser->Image->name ) }}">
    @endforeach
  @if($data3->count())
 @foreach($data3 as $currentUser)
<a href="{!! route('user.upload.image', ['id'=>$currentUser->user_id])  !!}">
    <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class ="fa fa-plus"></i>Upload Images</button>
</a>

@endforeach
@else
 <a href="{!! route('user.upload.image', ['id'=>$object->id])  !!}">
    <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class ="fa fa-plus"></i>Upload Images</button>
@endif  
 @endforeach
```

HomeController:

```
        public function getInfo($id) {
$data = user_information::where('id',$id)->get();
          $data3=Image::where('user_id',$id)->get();
     return view('test',compact('data','data3'));
```

Comment: You posted `upload.blade.php`, but your code invokes `create1`. Are you sure you are calling the right template?

Comment: @Dkna pass an `$id` variable into your `test()` method.

Comment: @Maraboc maybe we clear the chat on top a bit, and also can i not put the id number manually, but instead automatically? Like maybe have a for loop so that I won't have to do it for all?  Example maybe like if i go into user _information id = 3, then the user_id of  Images is 3

Comment: yes i know it's simply for testing purose only if the problem is solved the we will pass the correct ID ;) ok cleaning :)

Comment: But is it possible to make it find the id automatically instead of manually like what you had said just now? Sorry but am I confusing you?

Comment: To solve this issue login with a new user then you will have an existing id in the database ;) to be sure add `dd('user id =  '.$request->user_id);`

Comment: Ok i think I didn't say until this part, here is what I am making, when logging in, I am an admin and I can see all the users name which are all taken from the user_information table, and I can click on their name to see their information and also i can upload pictures so that i know how they look like. I have added a picture in my question on how my page look like when i click on the user name

Comment: ok now it's an other case :p i didn't have this information before so even my answer is not for this case, so i think you have to update even the routes ==> i will update my answer for that case ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't pass the user to your upload view, try to pass it like this :

```
public function upload(){
    $id = 1  //The wanted user or if the user is authenticated use Auth::id()
    $user = User::find($id);
    return view('upload')->withUser($user);
}
```

Or if the user is authenticated use Auth in the view :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/userUpload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {{  csrf_field()  }}

    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{auth()->id()}}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imageInput" class="control-label col-sm-3">Upload Image</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="file" name="file">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

For the second problem it's because in the route you have

```
Route::post('/UploadUser','UploadController@store');
```

and the your store method signature is

```
public function store(Request $request,$id){
```

The `$id` parameter that did the problem because it's not defined in the route so simply remove it from the method signatre

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);


    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $size = $image->getClientSize();
        $id = $request->user_id;  // here id is declared no need for the parameter
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);

        $Image = new Image;
        $Image->name = $name;
        $Image->size = $size;
         $Image->user_id = $id;         
        $Image->save();
    }
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

---

For the third case you have to change the routes from :

```
Route::get('/UploadUser/upload','UploadController@upload’);
```

to

```
Route::get('/UploadUser/{user}/upload','UploadController@upload’)->name('user.upload.image');
```

And in the view add the id in the upload button url maybe like this :

```
{!! route('user.upload.image', ['user'=>$currentUser->id])  !!}
```

Then in the upload method :

```
public function upload(user_information $user){ // route model binding here
    // dd($user);  //for testing only :)
    return view('upload')->withUser($user);
}
```

In the view change

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{auth()->id()}}">
```

To

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$user->id()}}">
```

And you are good to go ;)

```
@foreach ($data as $currentUser)
    <b>Name: </b>{{ $currentUser->Name }}<br><br>
    <a href="{{ url('/user/show/'.$currentUser->id.'/edit') }}">Edit</a><br>

    @if($currentUser->Image)
        <img src="{{ asset('public/images/' . $currentUser->Image->name ) }}">
    @endif  

    <a href="{!! route('user.upload.image', ['id'=>$currentUser->id])  !!}">

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You have miss to pass id in your where condition,

```
public function test(){
  $user = user_information::where('id',$id)->first();
  return view('create1', compact('user'));
}
```

and you have to pass your user data into this,

```
public function upload(){
 $user = user_information::where('id',$id)->first();
 return view(‘upload’,compact('user'));
}
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: thanks for replying i have tried your code but the error remain the same, Undefined variable: user, and the view is upload, just now i took the wrong templete

Comment: yeah but i edited my answer look forward i passed user variable into your upload method your upload view template not getting $user->id thats why it throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an `$id` variable into your `test()` method. Then please comment below what's the error next so I can follow you through.

**Update**

Since you don't want to pass an `id`. You can use:

```
public function test(){
    $u = Auth::user();
    $user = user_information::where('id', $u->id)->get();
    return view('upload', compact('user'));
}
```

**OR**

Try to use `first()` instead of `get()`.

**More option:**
I have noticed, you're using the `upload()` method here, why not passing the `$user` there? like so:

```
public function upload(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view(‘upload’, compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: Hi tks for replying, I seem to still get the error undefined user when i try your code and also i can't use first() since i am getting all the id and not just the first

Comment: @Dkna Ok great. then use `get()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

On your upload function, you have to pass the user variable because you use the `$user` in the view. So the controller will be

```
public function upload() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('upload', compact('user'));
}
```

do not forget to change the $user based on your need.