# Route function meaning

Tags: php, laravel

I am having some difficulty understanding what this code is doing. could someone explain it to me? I saw some people using it to redirect user to another page with it but I don't understand this part here `"['id'=>$data3->id]) ".`

Here is the full code: (from view page)

```
<a href="{!! route('user.upload.image', ['id'=>$data3->id])  !!}">
```

Controller (how data3 is being passed to view):

```
public function getInfo($id) {
      $data3=UserImage::where('user_id',$id)->get();
 return view('view',compact('data3'));
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/userUpload/{user}/create1','CreateController@create1')->name('user.upload.iamge');
Route::get('user/show/{id}','HomeController@getInfo')->name("user.show");
```

create1 controller:

```
    public function create1(personal_info $user){
     return view('create1')->withUser($user);
}
```

Comment: The user.upload.image is the name of the route

Comment: Mind showing us what the controller function for the route user.upload.image looks like? And the route itself?

Comment: I have added the controller and the route into the question @Cruncher

Comment: I meant the create1 function. But notice how the route has a variable in the url? User. That gets populated by the array which is the second argument to the route function. Though there's a lot of stuff wrong here. The name of the route doesn't match. And the name of the variable in the array doesn't match the name of the variable in the url

Comment: Sorry about that, took me some time to understand, have added the controller inside

Comment: And now that I see the controller another issue is the complex type as an argument. How is it supposed to take the url and build this complex object?

Comment: I was following this link over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927223/undefined-variableuser-laravel?noredirect=1#comment80813092_46927223 , the things that they were doing are similar to what I wanted to do so I had followed it but there are some stuff that I don't understand

Comment: Or maybe I post my codes in another question and could you help me see where I had gone wrong? @Cruncher

Comment: But do you know what does this part of the code do? "['id'=>$data3->id])  "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `routes`

```
Route::get('/userUpload/{user}/create1','CreateController@create1')->name('user.upload.iamge');
Route::get('user/show/{id}','HomeController@getInfo')->name("user.show");
```

The first `route` has a `parameter` `user` which must be passed to it anytime the `route` is called.

The second one also has an `id` parameter which must also be passed to it.

Passing the `parameter` values to the routes can be done in many ways. Eg.

By using the `route name`:

`<a href="{!! route('user.upload.image', ['user'=>$data3->id])  !!}">`

This method requires you to pass all the `parameters` as an array with the parameter name as the `key` of the array.

You can also call the route like:

`<a href="/userUpload/{$data3->id}/create1">`

Which requires nothing since the parameter has been hardcoded into the url.

Any time you accept `parameters` in your route, to pass them to your controller or `route function`, the must be listed on the order in which they are arranged.

So your `getInfo` passes the `id` parameter it received from the route to the controller

```
public function getInfo($id) {
      $data3=UserImage::where('user_id',$id)->get();
 return view('view',compact('data3'));
}
```

Comment: So your saying that I need to have something in my database first so that all this could work? @NorrisOduro

Comment: Yes.. But I think you're commenting under the wrong post

Comment: Wait I just realized also hahaha I thought that previous post nobody replied already so I ignored but that question is also related to this

Comment: Hahaha.. That's why I answered..  I saw it was you

Comment: Hope you understand the route parameters now

Comment: hahaha thank you so much for answering my question, let me go try it out first and I will get back to you

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer if you find it helpful

Comment: Sure, hold on let me try seeding my database first and see if it will work

Comment: @NorrisOdura yes I tried seeding the database with dummy information already and the upload button appear!! But what I want is to make that even without information I would still be able to upload image and when those image are uploaded their user_id will be the same as the id of the user_information table. Something like a one to one relationship

Comment: @blastme if you get this, i'll recommend you mark the answer so we continue with the other one